# Check how many times an Element appears in an Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native

I have arrays as

```
const [store, setStore] = useState([]);
const [count, setCount] = useState([]);
```

and a button which does

```
const addToCart = (item) => {
    setStore((currentItems) => [...currentItems, item]);
    setCount((prevCount) => [...prevCount, item]);
}
```

each item has its own text and key

so I would like to check if **count** has the same key of an element  in store **store**. If yes I would like to print how many of that item appears speceificially to each element. Ex: item 1 : 2 times, item 2: 1 time, item:3 ,12 times.

Comment: *"so I would like to..."*: what is holding you back?

Comment: You could use `new Set(store.map(s => s.myKey))` to get all unique keys

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.reduce()` method. So you could iterate over the store array and check if there is a object in store with the same key as item.

Could be something like this:

```
store.reduce((acc, current) => current.id === item.id ? acc += 1 : acc, 0)
```